# apache rewrite rules for locale specific pages

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I want to redirect users to a generic registration page if they come in without a locale in the URL, and specific registration page if they come in with a locale. For some reason the below doesn't work, let me know how to fix:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} source=actp
RewriteRule ^/(en|de|fr|zh|ja|jp|ko|kr)/web/login/registration $1/web/login/registration? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} source=actp
RewriteRule /web/login/registration /web/login/registration? [R=301,L]
```

example:

```
Before: website.com/web/login/registration
after: website.com/web/login/registration?source=actp 
before: website.com/kr/web/login/registration 
after: website.com/kr/web/login/registration?source=actp
```

Comment: Is this rewrite rule in Apache conf file or .htaccess? Are you just trying to add an `?` on to the end of the URL?

Comment: the rewrite rule is in a redirects.conf file. The intent of the second one was to redirect to the generic registration page if they arrive without a locale

Comment: i also need to add the ? to the end of the Url, yes

Comment: Sorry I edited my original question to ask about what you are really trying to achieve. Are you just trying to add a `?` to the end of the URL?  It might be helpful if you show some before/after URL examples of how you want the rewrites to work in your question.

Comment: Before: website.com/web/login/registration
after: website.com/web/login/registration?source=actp

before: website.com/kr/web/login/registration
after: website.com/kr/web/login/registration?source=actp

Answer (score 0):

Based on your before/after URL's, you are using the RewriteCond wrong here.  It would have expected the query string `source=actp` to match before even evaluating the RewriteRule. Since your before URL has no such query string, the RewriteRule will not even be evaluated. You don't need a RewriteCond here at all.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^/?((en|de|fr|zh|ja|jp|ko|kr)/)?web/login/registration$ /$2web/login/registration?source=actp [R=301,L]
```

Comment: @Swaroop No, the slash is included as part of the captured pattern. That is why I am using $2 instead of $1

Comment: @Swarrop I used the 0 or 1 for the whole language code + `/` portion of the URL so that only a single rule is needed.  Also added the `^/?` at the beginning so that others reading this answer in the future could use in server context (.conf file) or directory context (.htaccess).  You could just as easily swap the `^/?` in favor of just `^/` for your purposes.